# php - Unable to parse XML from string - Laravel Storage

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I am using [Orchestra/parser](https://github.com/orchestral/parser) for Laravel. I have installed it like the docs says, and I am trying to use it to read my XML file available on my server. I have a FTP server where automatic reports are being delivered to. I need to download files from my FTP server to my public disk:

```
    //Search for the files.
    $fileName = array_filter(Storage::disk('ftp')->files("/reports"), function ($file)
    {
        //This get filename from the FTP server (/reports folder), that includes the current date (YYYY-MM-DD) in the file name.
        return preg_match('/'.date("Y", time()).'\-'.date("m", time()).'\-'.date("d", time()).'(.*)\.[a-zA-Z]{3}/m', $file);

    });
```

I can find the files on my FTP server using above code. It works.

Next, I move the file from my FTP server to my public:

```
    //Set the new filename. We use this later on, when we move the file.
    $new_fileName = "milestone_report_".date("Y-m-d", time()).".xml";
    //$fileName[0] already includes the /reports path.
    $move_file = Storage::disk("public")->put("/reports/".$new_fileName."", Storage::disk('ftp')->get($fileName[0]));
```

This works too. Last I need to be able to read/get the content of the .xml file, using `XmlParser`. I do like described in the documentation:

```
//Load the new file, so we can use it with the "xml parser package"
$xml = XmlParser::load("/storage/app/public/reports/".$new_fileName."");
```

However, above gives me below error:

> **Unable to parse XML from string.**

- I have verified that the XML file is indeed located in my storage folder in Laravel. */storage/app/public/reports*

**UPDATE:**

**I have tried to load an XML file from my public folder `www.domain.com/xmlfile.xml` and this works like it should!**

How can I use the XmlParser to load from my storage?

  -

Comment: Why is XmlParser better than SimpleXML? Please share if you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this one out. Instead of using the `XmlParser::load()` function, I used the `XmlParser::extract()` function, and extracted the file using `Storage::disk()` like below:

```
$xml = XmlParser::extract(Storage::disk('public')->get("/reports/".$new_fileName.""));
```

The reason why it gave me the error "Unable to parse XML from string", was because previously I was only getting the path to my XML file (which is just a string). `XmlParser` needs the file loaded directly into the method.